# Interpolate model values into dynamic template using SendGridMessage

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I'm building my email for sending with the [SendGrid library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SendGrid/)'s `SendGridMessage` object.

I'm defining my values as an anonymous type which I'm injecting with the SendGridMessage's `SetTemplateData()` method:

```
var mail = new SendGridMessage
{
    Attachments = new List<Attachment>(),
    From = new EmailAddress()
    {
        Email = emailConfig.FromAddress,
        Name = $"Redacted on behalf of {booking.Member.Client.Name}"
    },
    TemplateId = EmailConstants.ConfirmationEmailTemplateId,
    Subject = "Redacted"
};

mail.Personalizations = new List<Personalization>() {
    new Personalization() {
        Tos = new List<EmailAddress>() {
            new EmailAddress() {
                Email = memberEmail,
                Name = memberName
            },
        }
    }
};
var data = new
{
    memberName = memberName,
    dateOfAppointment = booking.Date.ToString("dd MMM yy"),
    timeOfAppointment = booking.Date.ToString("HH:mm"),
    questionnaireLink = questionnaireLink
};
mail.SetTemplateData(data);
```

The email gets sent out perfectly fine, but in the email template, my tags `{memberName}`, `{dateofAppointment}`, etc. are not being replaced by the values indicated here.

I've found [handlebars](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars) but no C# guide to use them; I'd assume the data I'm submitting above would work so long as I get the tags right in the template... Am I right?

How do I replace the indicated tags (`{memberName}`, `{dateofAppointment}`, etc.) in my dynamic template with my data values?

Comment: Can you show your email template as well? Handlebars templates must use double curly braces, like `{{memberName}}`, not `{memberName}`. I suspect that the problem might be in the template, not your C# code.

Comment: @NateBarbettini I've also been thinking that's what it is. I'll make the change and get back to you with the template if it doesn't work

Comment: No problem, glad it was an easy fix!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your template contains tags using double-brace syntax, like `{{memberName}}`. `{memberName}` (single braces) won't work.

From the [SendGrid docs on Handlebars syntax](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars#basic-replacement),

```html
<!-- Template -->
<p>Hello {{ firstName }}</p>
```

```js
// Test data
{ "firstName": "Ben" }
```

```html
<!-- Resulting HTML -->
<p>Hello Ben</p>
```

If this syntax is used properly in the template, the code in your question will work just fine.